# VSCode: extensions not working; how can I troubleshoot this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode and tried installing some extensions, but none of them work. Are there any troubleshooting steps I can take? They all appear to be successfully installed, but when I try to use intellisense etc, they don't do anything.

Comment: it's because you must be using other apps or multiple tabs on chrome, it's slow down your speed and extensions stop working, restart your pc it may works...